# Does model theory in mathematics have any usefulness in the modeling of physical systems?

Tags: mathematical-physics, models, category-theory

The term *Model Theory* in mathematics seems to have a somewhat precise definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory). Reading through that reference you'll largely see discussions strictly relating to mathematical concepts, but one can see topics discussed that might have a connection to modeling physical systems such as stability and completeness.

So does Model Theory have a useful place in the modeling of physical systems?

My motivation for this question: I'm searching to find a field or discipline in mathematics that pulls together a collection of mathematical tools and methods that may not only be useful, but necessary to consider when one is faced with modeling physical systems. I'm looking for mathematics that lead to theorems (either proven or unproven) that say what you need, what you can do , and what you can't do in modeling physical systems.

So if Model Theory doesn't fit that bill, then is there another area of mathematics that I should rather explore?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think the *only* thing mathematical "model theory" shares with physical modelling is the name.

Comment: If this approach to physics has any attraction, then you might also want to check "Category Theory".

Comment: @ACuriousMind But it appears that Model Theory at least encompasses stability theory as I pointed out. And the theorems and lemmas of stability theory have lots to do with modeling physical systems and are very useful in determining say for example if a system is stable or not. I know because I have experience in that area. So what about the other areas considered in Model Theory?

Comment: Physical theories don't factor and nest quite like mathematical ones because they are not driven by ever more relaxed axioms.

Comment: @docscience: Oh, that is a confusion about what "stability theory" in this context is, the "stability theory" in model theory is about [this notion of a "stable" theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_theory), not about the stability of solutions of PDEs.

Comment: @ACuriousMind is correct, mathematical model theory is the study of mathematica structures using mathematical logic, and has little to do with physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind thanks for clarifying the context of stability theory. So then is it so that each topic in physics gathers its own set of mathematical tools that suit a physical model that describes that area? Isn't there an area of mathematics that's universal, setting up some basic principles by which to model? We look at nature and want to model it. Other than our own personal experience and training what else can lead us to chose one system of mathematics over another? That's what I'm really seeking to answer.

Comment: That area of mathematics you have in mind is probably just logic. Of course a mathematical model of a physical system has to be logically consistent, but just doing some "abstract nonsense" without any physical context is probably not going to get you anywhere. Oftentimes what is more constraining are basic physical principles, like causality, unitarity and symmetries.